# How can I authorize South Korea for Geopermission call forwarding on my twilio app?

Tags: twilio

It says the calls aren't forwarding because geopermissions aren't enabled for south korea but south korea isn't listed as an option under geo permissions. But it is listed as an option for phone numbers to call to and get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You need to check your geo permissions for voice calls, here in the console: https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/settings/geo-permissions

You want to look for the option "Korea Republic of" rather than South Korea.

Hope this helps!